# Play audiotrack after stop previously audio played before Android

Tags: android, audio, audiotrack

Here is a function for playing some audiotrack.

**the main code for calling this function:**

```
play(a);
play(b);
```

**and the play function is:**

```
public void play(byte[] audioData) {
        try {
                audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                        getSampleRate(),
                        getChannelCount(),
                        getAudioFormat(),
                        audioData.length,
                        AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);


            audioTrack.play();
            audioTrack.write(audioData, 0, audioData.length);   


        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Log.e("AudioTrack", "Playback Failed");
        }
    }
```

but this app is playing two audio data together at the same time

```
|----a----|
|--b--|
```

**I want to play b[] after a[], like this:**

```
|----a----||--b--|
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to detect the end of audio track play of audio A. To do this you need to first get the audio length of audio A and set the audio track notification marker as follows

```
audioTrack.setNotificationMarkerPosition(audioLength);
```

Then implement the playback position update listener, and when the marker is reached you can start playing the audio B as follows

```
audioTrack.setPlaybackPositionUpdateListener(new OnPlaybackPositionUpdateListener() {
     @Override
     public void onPeriodicNotification(AudioTrack track) {
               // nothing to do
     }
     @Override
     public void onMarkerReached(AudioTrack track) {
              // play the audio B here 
     } 
});
```